# Insurance Area 51 Proposal

Tags: discussion

I created an Area 51 proposal for [Insurance](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102020/insurance). Whether or not it survives is a question of whether or not enough people follow it, ask questions, and vote-up questions.

The idea behind the site is to cover insurance topics, including those not covered here. [Many insurance questions are off-topic here](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2223/are-questions-about-insurance-on-topic) and I believe there should be a place to discuss them.

My question is: could an explanation be added to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to clarify what about insurance is on-topic here. Also, (assuming the site survives), can a link be added to the SE Insurance site next to that explanation?

Answer (score 7):

There are currently 8 tags for insurance -

- insurance - 230 posts
- health insurance - 122 posts
- life insurance - 91 posts
- car insurance - 60 posts
- home insurance - 27 posts
- deposit insurance - 14 posts
- title insurance - 10 posts
- national insurance - 7 posts

That's 561 total posts, a decent number. What leads you to believe insurance is anything but welcome here? Yes, we can explicitly add insurance to 'on topic'.

I wish you well with a new stack, but, in my opinion, the insurance questions that don't fit here will not be enough to support a separate stack.

Update - I added

> Insurance, including life, home, auto, health

to the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) I'd appreciate any feedback or advice on rewording.

Comment: There are many lines of insurance that are not related to personal finance. Obviously there is overlap in personal lines (like those represented by the tags you list), but there is a lot more to insurance. I hope there is enough interest but so far I need 3 more followers to survive the first cut-off.

Comment: The first sign that a new stack would work is an abundance of questions, presumably closed as off topic on a current site, which indicate interest. You propose a niche which is a subset of what we see here. In other words, of 15000 questions, nearly 600 are insurance. Even if all questions were off topic, those 600 would not support a new stack. That's all, and it's just my opinion. Not looking to debate any further. As I wrote above, we'll add insurance to the on topic here.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I appreciate them very much. It's my first attempt at proposing a site so even if it fails, I'm glad for the learning experience :)

Answer (score 1):

The [Insurance](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102020/insurance) proposal has been removed from Area 51:

> Inactive proposals that do not receive any activity for one month are subject to deletion. Occasionally, proposals may be removed from Area 51 for reasons of moderation: spam, off topic, abuse, etc. For more information, see the [FAQ](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: Yes. As I answered above, a topic that we cover here pretty well.